Failed to apply the value function for the gauge 'jvm.memory.used'
We are currently getting errors of this type in a Quarkus native app. The app works fine, and the errors are really sporadic (once a week/month, maybe?). Depending on usage, this app has a high consumption of RAM when generating big xlsx files with POI.
We understand that it's memory related, but the error is not necessarily related to any execution (the last execution was about 30 minutes before the error, while the next one was 30 minutes later).
What we want to understand if this is a framework error (something that should be reported), a dev error (something we can fix/tweak), or if it's just expected to happen.
Technologies used:

Quarkus 3.8.5
Java 17

Also happens with:

Quarkus 3.8.5
Java 21
Built with: GraalVM for JDK 21 Community 21.0.2 (Java version: 21.0.2+13, vendor version: GraalVM CE 21.0.2+13.1) via ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-community:21-ol7 image

Error:
[io.mic.cor.ins.int.DefaultGauge] (executor-thread-348) Failed to apply the value function for the gauge 'jvm.memory.used'. Note that subsequent logs will be logged at debug level.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: committed = 1660640336 should be < max = 1659895808
    at java.management@17.0.9/java.lang.management.MemoryUsage.<init>(MemoryUsage.java:166)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.AbstractMemoryPoolMXBean.memoryUsage(AbstractMemoryPoolMXBean.java:75)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.GenScavengeMemoryPoolMXBeans$EdenMemoryPoolMXBean.getUsage(GenScavengeMemoryPoolMXBeans.java:94)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmMemory.getUsage(JvmMemory.java:79)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmMemory.getUsageValue(JvmMemory.java:69)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jvm.JvmMemoryMetrics.lambda$bindTo$0(JvmMemoryMetrics.java:82)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:53)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$5(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:338)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:75)
    at io.prometheus.client.Collector.collect(Collector.java:45)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.findNextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:204)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:219)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry$MetricFamilySamplesEnumeration.nextElement(CollectorRegistry.java:152)
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.write004(TextFormat.java:71)
    at io.prometheus.client.exporter.common.TextFormat.writeFormat(TextFormat.java:53)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.scrape(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:154)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.scrape(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:149)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.scrape(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.export.handlers.PrometheusHandler.doHandle(PrometheusHandler.java:63)
    at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.export.handlers.PrometheusHandler.handle(PrometheusHandler.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.micrometer.runtime.export.handlers.PrometheusHandler.handle(PrometheusHandler.java:18)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.BlockingHandlerDecorator.lambda$handle$0(BlockingHandlerDecorator.java:48)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:191)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$internalExecuteBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:210)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:807)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:210)

Monitoring tool at error time:
jvm_memory_used_bytes (eden space) went from ~1.55 GB to ~14.8 MB

jvm_memory_used_bytes (old generation space) went from ~232.67 MB to ~251.04 MB

Also found:

https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/6814
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35196


This seems a GraalVM bug. Looks like there is a fix here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/pull/6930
What version of GraalVM did you use to create the Quarkus APP?

The fix is part of the GraalVM for JDK 22 release and onward.
If you want you can try it with -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:jdk-23

According to the comments in the issue the error happens because of a GraalVM bug fixed here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/pull/6930.
However this is only available on GraalVM for JDK 22 release and onwards (at the date of this post).
If it helps, Quarkus can be built to native mode using an alternative GraalVM with:
-Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:jdk-23

In this case it will use Mandrel for JDK 23.
